# How to add custom field in default registration form of Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel

In one of my **Laravel 5.6** applications, I need to add a few more fields in the default registration form.

So I've added only one field to test [phone_no] in the default registration form **registration.blade.php**, and also add *phone_no* **RegisterController**, but when I click on the register button it shows the following errors:

```
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'phone_no' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Jahid Hossain, jahid.cse18@gmail.com, $2y$10$wYg6jAihCz.v09PUXngF/ekjNvZgxb4Rq4GI3i.glfzXt37oGnbSO, 2018-04-20 06:24:27, 2018-04-20 06:24:27))
```

So here is the **migration file** code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('status')->default('active');
        $table->string('created_by')->default('SYSTEM');
        $table->string('modified_by');
        $table->string('phone_no');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And here is the code of **RegisterController**:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'created_by' => $data['email'],
        'phone_no'  => $data['phone_no'],
    ]);
}
```

So I think I am missing something. Can anyone tell me how can I add one/more fields in the **Laravel 5.6** default registration form and save those field successfully...

- Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please add your custom field in below way.

In your model add the your custom field in `protected $fillable=['name', 'email', 'password', 'created_by', 'phone_no']` in your model

Answer (score 2):

```
protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'email', 'password', 'created_by', 'phone_no', 'address'] // in your model
```

also add these field to your migration also

`phone_no` default means you are sending `phone_no` blank.