# Custom fields in laravel 5.6 default auth causing error

Tags: php, laravel

Before posting this question i've already referred to [How to add custom field in default registration form of Laravel 5.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49935424/how-to-add-custom-field-in-default-registration-form-of-laravel-5-6)

But no solution for my problem. I wanted to add custom fields in my laravel 5.6 fresh install with it's default make:auth.

this is my migration for creating user table

[image]

this is my registercontrller for auth and i've implemented my custom fields here

[image]

and here is fillable array of my model user.php which extends authenticble

[image]

This is dd() response from register controller

[image]

And in the end here is the error that i'm getting after doing all this.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated . 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your table column name must be "fname"  not "Fname"

Comment: Your fillables array has a typo error i guess. You have used Fname in migration and in fillables you have used fname

Comment: @EtibarRustemzade Thanks alot you solve my problem and save me time . Nauman brother thanks to you also

Comment: @EtibarRustemzade i did that please let me know can i chat with you i've another problem encountered with this problem

Comment: of course @HumzaMalik

Comment: @EtibarRustemzade {{ Auth::user()->name }} is not working now. Where i can set up my user()->name as Lname . " " .Fname

Comment: You can use method  ‘name()’ is in User model   And in method return $this->Lname;

Comment: @EtibarRustemzade i can't find any name() method in User model

Comment: add this to your user model `public function name()
    {
        return $this->Lname;
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your table column's name must be "fname" not "Fname"

Answer (score 0):

Either add the default value directly in mysql table column fname default = null 
OR do PHP migration rollback first if migration is already done then add a new migration after that add this in up function

```
 Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->string('fname')->nullable();
      });
```